# Relação entre 3 entidades

Tags: doctrine, symfony-2

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
+----------+  +----------------------+ +------------+
| Produtos |  | ProdutosVsCategorias | | Categorias |
+----------+  +----------------------+ +------------+
- ID          - ID                     - ID
- TITULO      - ID_PRODUTO             - TITULO
              - ID_CATEGORIA
```

1. A tabela `Produtos` contém todos os meus produtos
2. A tabela `ProdutosVsCategorias` tem uma relação com a tabela `Produtos` e `Categorias`.
3. A relação entre as tabelas `Produtos` e `ProdutosVsCategorias` se dá através  dos campos `ID` e `ID_PRODUTO` respectivamente e é OneToMany.
4. A relação entre as tabelas `ProdutosVsCategorias` e `Categorias` se dá através dos campos `ID_CATEGORIA` e `ID` respectivamente e é ManyToOne.

Para cada tabela, criei uma entidade, porém não sei como fazer a relação entre as entidades no Symfony utilizando o Doctrine.

Ao instanciar a entidade `Produto`, preciso saber quais as categorias estão associadas ao produto.

Ao instanciar uma categoria, também preciso saber quais os produtos associados a categoria.

Como fazer a relação entre entidades utilizando o exemplo acima?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende do caso. Você pode criar uma relação *many-to-many* entre as entidades `Produto` e `Categoria`, ou duas relações *many-to-one*, sendo uma entre `Produto` e `ProdutoVsCategoria`, e outra entre `ProdutoVsCategoria` e `Categoria`. A diferença é que quando você faz o relacionamento usando duas relações *many-to-one*, é possível customizar a entidade intermediária (mais atributos, por exemplo).

Essa explicação está na documentação do [Doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html):

> Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes.
>
> http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Mas vou explicar como fazê-lo usando duas entidades.

Primeiro, crie as classes para as tabelas `Categorias` e `Produtos`.

Classe `Produto`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity;
 * @ORM\Table(name="Produtos")
 */
class Produto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categoria", mappedBy="produtos")
     */
    private $categorias;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $titulo;
}
```

Classe `Categoria`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity;
 * @ORM\Table(name="Categorias")
 */
class Categoria
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Produto", inversedBy="categorias")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ProdutosVsCategorias")
     */
    private $produtos;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $titulo;
}
```

(não se esqueça de adequar os *namespaces* aos *namespaces* do seu projeto.)

Depois disso, basta usar o comando `php app/console doctrine:schema:create` para criar o esquema de tabelas no banco de dados configurado no seu arquivo `app/config/parameters.yml`.